# IE11/Fixed Header/Scrollable Table - Vertical/Horizontal Scrolling causing scroll to lag when mouse flickers between Text Beam/Default

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer

With the following AngularJS directive I have an issue in IE 11 only, which I thought was attributed to my directive but seems related to my cursor position above table cell text.  It happens when I scroll vertically horizontally as the cursor remains above text.    I observe the mouse flickering between the text (I) vertical beam and the arrow default cursor.   When I move the mouse during this flicker the scroll responds more smoothly.

When the mouse is stationary as I rotate the wheel, the table scroll lags for about 5-6 seconds before my mouse stops flickering (above text only) in an html table cell then it goes back to normal as the table responds again.

What is going on here, and how do I remedy this problem?

**Template**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div ng-controller="ActionController" ng-app="Action">
       <init-action/>
        ActionItems
        <div class="tableheader">
        <table id="actionitems" class="table-striped table-condensed table-bordered sortable action grid"> <!--datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions"-->
             <thead>
                <tr>  
                    <th>
                        Edit
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('actionitemid')" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}">
                        ID                       
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('actionitemtitle')" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}">
                        Action Item Title 
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('status')" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}">
                        Status
                    </th>                         
                    <th ng-click="sort('critlevel')" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}">
                        Criticality
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('assignor')" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}">
                        Assignor
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('owner')" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}">
                        Owner
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('altowner')" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}">
                        Alt Owner
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('approver')" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}">
                        Approver
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('assigneddate')" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}">
                        Assigned Date
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('duedate')" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}">
                        Due Date
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('ecd')" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}">
                        ECD
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('completiondate')" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}">
                        Completed
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('closedate')" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}">
                        Closed
                    </th>
                </tr>
             </thead> 
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="tablebody">
            <table class="table-striped table-condensed table-bordered grid">
                <tbody init-table>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <divider></divider>
      <div class="msg" layout-align="center">
        <span ng-bind-html="msg">{{msg}}</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
directive('initTable', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        //transclude: true,
        templateUrl: '/app/tool/action/ActionItemTable.html',
        controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
            $scope.scrollBarWidth = function(){
                    var outer = document.createElement("div");
                    outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
                    outer.style.width = "100px";
                    outer.style.msOverflowStyle = "scrollbar"; // needed for WinJS apps

                    document.body.appendChild(outer);

                    var widthNoScroll = outer.offsetWidth;
                    // force scrollbars
                    outer.style.overflow = "scroll";

                    // add innerdiv
                    var inner = document.createElement("div");
                    inner.style.width = "100%";  
                    outer.appendChild(inner);        

                    var widthWithScroll = inner.offsetWidth;

                    // remove divs
                    outer.parentNode.removeChild(outer);

                    return widthNoScroll - widthWithScroll;
            }
            $scope.setMarginsWidths = function(){
                $scope.flag = 0;
                refresh = 1;
                var msie = document.documentMode;
                if(refresh){ 
                    $timeout(refreshEvery,1);
                }
                
                function refreshEvery(){
                    if ($scope.flag == 0 || window.devicePixelRatio != $scope.devicePixelRatio)
                    {   
                        $scope.flag = 1;
                        $scope.devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;
                        var headers = angular.element(document.querySelector('div.tableheader table.grid thead tr')).children();
                        var cells = angular.element(document.querySelector('div.tablebody table.grid tbody tr:nth-child(1)')).children();
                        angular.forEach(cells, function(cell, idx){
                            var cellwidth = cell.getBoundingClientRect().width;
                            headers[idx].width = cellwidth;
                        });
                    }

                    if (refresh && !msie)
                        $scope.refreshingPromise = $timeout(refreshEvery,1);
                    else{
                         $scope.isRefreshing = false;
                         $timeout.cancel($scope.refreshingPromise);
                    }
                    
                    //angular.element(document.querySelector('html')).attr("style", "margin-right: " + 0*$scope.scrollBarWidth() + "px !important");
                    angular.element(document.querySelector('div.tableheader')).attr("style", "margin-right: " + $scope.scrollBarWidth() + "px !important");
                    angular.element(document.querySelector('div.tablebody')).attr("style", "margin-right " + $scope.scrollBarWidth() + "px !important");    
                }
            }
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.init().then(function(){
                
            });
        }
    }
}).directive('ngRepeatDone', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function($scope, $timeout){
            $scope.devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;
            $scope.setMarginsWidths();
            var tablebody = document.querySelector('div.tablebody');
            var tableheader = document.querySelector('div.tableheader');
            angular.element(tablebody).on("scroll", function(elem, attrs){  //activate when #center scrolls  
                left = $scope.CommonService.offset(angular.element(document.querySelector("div.tablebody table.grid"))[0]).left; //save #center position to var left
                (angular.element(tableheader)[0]).scrollLeft = -1*left + $scope.scrollBarWidth();
            }); 
        }
    }
});
```

**Video Capture Showing Issue**

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry that I could not reprodcue the issue with some code missed. Could you provide the complete code which could reprodcue the issue? Or you could make a simple demo in jsbin like this https://jsbin.com/bapocudagi/edit?html,js,output .

Comment: Hi Jennifer,  thank you so much for the response,  Can you indicate what you would like posted?  I will post the table template too.

Comment: The page including  the element initTable, ngRepeatDone of your directive.

Answer (score 0):

I've run your code and reprodcued the mouse flickering issue. From my point of view , this may be the browser's behaviour.

When you scroll the bar, the mouse will change between the style I and arrow.

This is because IE detect the content in the table, it will become I.If detecting the blank part in the table, it will become arrow.

About the table scroll lags for about 5-6 seconds, I have not seen that.

Here is my running result:

[image]

Comment: I believe I have isolated the issue on my machine.  When I click in the table, in my actual running code, bringing focus to the table, then start scrolling, that is when this problem occurs in my actual app.  I will continue to find a solution.   Thank you.  I will look for a click event somewhere in my app and find out how to stop the behavior, hopefully through preventDefault.

Comment: Also, to note, the behavior occurs when I use the mouse wheel, and have focus in the table.  I don't see the issue with the scroll bar method of scrolling.

Comment: I'm sorry that it seems that I misunderstand your meaning. I'm now curious about your page's behavior.Could you show a gif screenshot to show me what is the odd behaviour? Do you mean that the header line have a delay to render when scrolling? If so, here is a helpful link:https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3719

Comment: Removing a necessary dependency (Webix UI) in my codebase eliminated the issue <script src="/app/js/webix-6.3.2/codebase/webix.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  I am yet unsure why it is causing this problem.

Comment: Also, see edits to my question at the end of the question, thanks!  Note, I am not using ui-grid, I made my own grid.

Comment: This is a js file. And I guess that there may be some event or function related to the mouse hover in that file which has caused the conflict and caused the odd behaviour.